# Why os.path.dirname returns /usr/local/bin not the python script's path?

Tags: python

For another simple test, I made this code (file name is test3.py) and I put in in /home/ckim/python/test3 directory.

```
import os.path as osp
import sys

def add_path(path):
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, path)

this_dir = osp.dirname(__file__)

lib_path = osp.join(this_dir, 'lib')
add_path(lib_path)

from pack1.ppp import ppp

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ('starting main..')
    ppp()
```

When I run the code, `this_dir` value gives me `/usr/local/dir` when I expected it to be `/home/ckim/python/test3`. What is the problem?

Comment: reduce to minimum test case of `print(__file__, os.path.dirname(__file__))` and confirm its still happening

Comment: @donkopotamus, hi, it prints `('test3.py', '')`. I don't know why.

Comment: Then that's the correct result ... if you are running it from that directory the relative directory name is `''`

Comment: @donkopotamus, Ah, I see. that was the point. So dirname() returns the relative directory name! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [os.path.realpath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) as well to make it work:

```
this_dir = osp.dirname(osp.realpath(__file__))
```

`os.getcwd()` might also solve your problem.

Comment: yes, realpath() works, but I didn't know os.path.dirname() returns relative path.